# Very significant issue about Component and bindings

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, angular-components

Let's consider the following code:

```
angular.module('app').component('foo', {

  bindings: {
    callback: '&'
  },
  controller: function() {
    // ...
    this.callback();
  }
});
```

and the corresponding view:

```
<foo callback="$ctrl.myCallback()">
   <span ng-click="$ctrl.myCallBack()">Press me</span>
</foo>
```

My question is why do we need bindings since we can simply use `$ctrl.myCallback()` inside the HTML code of templateUrl without applying any kind of bindings? ***With components, the isolated scope of the component is known to the view, so once again why to use bindings?*** 
*However, would it be possible to unit test the component if it does not have bindings?*

Comment: Because the scope of a component is isolated, and the component thus doesn't have access to the outer controller, and thus to its myCallback function. Even if it had, you don't want your component to be usable only in a context where some myCallback function exists. You want the user of the component to be able to specify any callback it wants to.

Comment: Fair enough. However, could you explain why the above code(I added some) does not work? ng-click does not call the corresponding function of the component's controller. Moreover, why do I have to use the prefix $ctrl? I think there is something I am missing.

Comment: Your component doesn't do transclusion, so this code doesn't make sense. The span inside foo will be replaced by the template of the component. Please come up with a complete, minimal example reproducing the problem, preferrably in a plunkr. $ctrl is the default name under which the controller of a component is stored in its $scope.

Comment: Could you please have a look at https://jsfiddle.net/e608rrj0/4/ ? I deleted templateUrl from the component. Thank you very much

Comment: **Describe the problem.** "Significant issue" is not a problem statement. Tell us what the expected behavior should be. Put a brief summary of the problem in the title of your question.